# How to compose partial functions with multiple parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, lambda, higher-order-functions, partialfunction

```scala
    val f1 = (x: Int) => x match {
      case x1 => x * 2
    }
    
    val f2 = (x: Int, y: Int) => (x, y) match {
      case (x1, y1) => x1 + y1
    }
    
    val f3 = f1.compose(f2)
```

Expecting f3 to be a partial function from (Int, Int) => Int but I get the following error

```plaintext
Found:    (f2 : (Int, Int) => Int)
Required: Any => Int
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Function1.html#compose%5BA%5D(g:A=%3ET1):A=%3ER) suggests, `compose` specifically composes two instances of `Function1`, that is two instances of a unary function.

If you want to keep your code as is, the way to do this is

```
f1 andThen f2.curried
```

If you look at the documentation closely

`compose` returns a new function f s.t. `f(x) == apply(g(x))`

`andThen` returns a new function f s.t. `f(x) == g(apply(x))`

Note the difference in order of application. Yes, I know the naming is rather is confusing.

Edit: It is confusing which way you want these to apply. The other way around is provided in Jorg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`scala.Function1.compose`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#compose%5BA%5D(g:A=%3ET1):A=%3ER) and [`scala.PartialFunction.compose`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#compose%5BR%5D(k:PartialFunction%5BR,A%5D):PartialFunction%5BR,B%5D) only take functions as parameters which have a single parameter. But `f2` has two parameters, therefore, it is not type-compatible with the parameter type of `compose`.

You can convert `f2` to a single-parameter function which takes its parameters as a [`scala.Tuple`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) using the [`scala.Function2.tupled`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function2.html#tupled:((T1,T2))=%3ER) method:

```scala
val f3 = f1.compose(f2.tupled)
```

Note: `f3` is now a `Function1[Tuple2[Int, Int], Int]` aka `((Int, Int)) => Int`, i.e. it needs to be applied like this:

```scala
f3((2, 3))
```

To turn it into a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]` aka `(Int, Int) => Int`, you can use the [`scala.Function.untupled`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function$.html#untupled%5BT1,T2,R%5D(f:((T1,T2))=%3ER):(T1,T2)=%3ER) method:

```scala
val f4 = Function.untupled(f3)
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/ovzgnKMwRGaNb0g8V3DN9w)

Also note that neither `f1` nor `f2` are [`scala.PartialFunction`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html)s. `f1` is a [`scala.Function1[Int, Int]` aka `(Int) => Int`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) and `f2` is a [`scala.Function2[Int, Int, Int]` aka `(Int, Int) => Int`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function2.html).